# How to open word file in background using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I am working on creating multiple documents from source document.

I am using:

```
objWordApp.Documents.Open("D:\Template\Aptletter.doc")
```

I modify the above document and save in another folder.

While creating documents, word files are opening and closing multiple times. So user unable to do another work on the same PC.

*How to stop open file or Is there any method to modify document without above method?*

So please suggest

Thanks in Advance

DEV

Comment: use `backgroundWorker`

Comment: You can change the visibility of the documents opened: word.Visible = False.

Comment: thank you for your reply.But document is already opened when I am using 'objWordApp.Documents.Open("D:\Template\Aptletter.doc")'.So is it possible to open document in hide mode.?

Comment: @DEVRAJ use what N55PEC mentioned but do it before you open the file...

Comment: @N55PEC I placed it before like   objWordApp.Visible = False
            objWordApp.Documents.Open("D:\Template\Aptletter.doc"),But no use

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of a word document being controlled via interop can be set using the `WordApplication.Visible` attribute.

This attribute is, as you can see, at the Application level. If you've already opened a document using that `WordApplication`, you can't suddenly make the application invisible using the attribute.

What you *can* do, though, is create another instance of `WordApplication`. Call it InvisibleWordApplication for clarity, and set `InvisibleWordApplication.Visible = false` right from the start. Then open your document using that application, and you should be set.